# Unhandled Rejection at: TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

The console says the error appears in `index.js`. I'm trying to export the currency commands code from another file and import it here, just so it looks a bit nicer.

Error: `Unhandled Rejection at: TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined`

```
//index.js
if (command === 'coinflip') {
    client.commands.get('coinflip').execute(message, args);
    }
```

```
//coins.js
module.exports = [
{
    name: "coinflip",
    async execute(message, args) {
    //coinflip code here
}}]
```

If any of you can see the issue (sorry if it's obvious!) and help me out, that would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: The code you've posted in `coins.js` doesn't make sense. Can you post a more detailed version?

Comment: @MaxG is that a bit better?

Comment: You export an Array.. arrays do not have a `get` command. Perhaps you meant to export a `Map`? Or to call `find` on the Array?

Answer (score 0):

For the code to work, `client.commands` must be an object that contains the imported array created in `coin.js`.

`.get` must be a function on the `client.commands` object that returns the desired object within the coin.js array.

To await the output of `execute`, it must executed be within an asynchronous function (unless you're using bleeding-edge JS). You should also execute it in a `try/catch` block, which will eliminate the 'Unhandled Rejection' error.

```
// index.js

const coins = require('./coin.js')

const client = {
  commands: {
    cmds: [...coins],

    get(cmd) { 
      return commands.cmds.filter(item => item.name === cmd)
    }
  }
}

const doThing = async () => {
  try {
    switch (cmd) {
      case 'coinflip':
        await client.commands.get('coinflip').execute(msg, args)
        break
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}

;(async () => {
  const cmd = 'coinflip'
  await doThing(cmd)
})()
```

```
// coins.js

module.exports = [
  {
    name: "coinflip",
    async execute(message, args) {
      //coinflip code here
    }
  }
]
```

This seems like overkill though and could be simplified as:

```
// index.js

const coinflip = require('./coin.js')

const client = {
  commands: {
    coinflip
  }
}

const doThing = async cmd => {
  try {
    await client.commands[cmd].execute(msg, args)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}

;(async () => {
  const cmd = 'coinflip'
  await doThing(cmd)
})()
```

```
// coins.js

module.exports = {
  async execute(message, args) {
    //coinflip code here
  }
}
```

Comment: Using the second option, can I 'load up' multiple commands at once?

Comment: I'm still having trouble with `.execute` not being a function. What could be wrong, or is there something I need to do first to be able to use `execute`?